# makefile error with 2 Dirs, 3 header Files

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I have 2 Dirs and 3 header files stored in them, as follows:

Dir A : contains Header files A and C
Dir B : contains Header file B

Dirs A and B are sub-directories of a dir named Apps (which is a subdir of some other dirs).

Basically, the problem occurred in a similar situation, from which I have isolated the problem. Hence, the C++ source files shown below are trivial:

Header file A.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class A
{
};

#endif  /// A_H
```

Header file C.h:

```
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

#include "B.h"

class C
{
};
```

Tester for A.h, viz. TestA.cpp:

```
/** TestA.cpp */

#include "A.h"

/// ...

int main()
{
}
```

Tester for C.h, viz. TestC.cpp:

```
/** TestC.cpp */

#include "C.h"

/// ...

int main()
{
}
```

Dir B contains 1 C++ header file B.h and its tester TestB.cpp, both trivial:

Header file B.h:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "A.h"

class B
{
};

#endif  /// B_H
```

Tester for B.h, viz. TestB.cpp:

```
/** TestB.cpp */

#include "B.h"

/// ...

int main()
{
}
```

The 3 testers TestA.cpp, TestB.cpp and TestC.cpp have 3 makefiles: MakeA, MakeB and MakeC respectively. MakeA and MakeC are in dir A and MakeB is in dir B, as expected.

I am not showing MakeA and MakeB, since they work correctly.

The error occurs in MakeC:

```
CPP = g++
OFLAG = -o
CFLAG = -std=c++11 -c

PROG1 = TestC

HC = C
HB = B
HA = A

HBDIR = ../B/
HADIR = ./

IHBDIR = -I$(HBDIR)
IHADIR = -I$(HADIR)

all : $(PROG1).o $(PROG1).exe run1

$(PROG1).o : $(PROG1).cpp $(HADIR)$(HC).h $(HBDIR)$(HB).h $(HADIR)$(HA).h
    $(CPP) $(CFLAG) $(IHADIR) $(IHBDIR) $<

$(PROG1).exe : $(PROG1).o
    $(CPP) $(OFLAG) $@ $^

run1:
    $(PROG1)
```

This make file is unable to locate header file A (which is #included by header file B) and gives the following error:

```
In file ...
../B/B.h fatal error: A.h : no such file or directory
#include "A.h"
compilation terminated
```

Evidently, make is searching for A.h in B.h's dir (since B.h #includes A.h). However, I have defined the symbol HADIR (as ./), which should have caused make to search in the default dir, which is Dir A.

Please note:

1) The header file references are simple and linear : A.h is #included by B.h which is #included by C.h.

2) I don't wish to hard-code dir paths in the source files. They must be stored only in the makefiles, since that's one of the purposes of makefiles.

3) There are 2 solutions to the problem that I know of:
   a) Relocate C.h, its tester and makefile to a dir C. However, I don't want to do this, since A.h and C.h are semantically related.
   b) In MakeC, define HADIR as ../A, rather than ./ But I don't understand why I should do that.

The BAT file that invokes the make utility with MakeC as input makefile, is as follows:

```
cd /f/Files/C/SW/Applications/Samples/C++Samples/Introductory/
      Classes/Apps/A/
make -f MakeC
```

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error; this makefile seems to work. Can you give us a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Beware you don't terminate `#ifndef C_H` in C.h

Comment: Your makefile and code seem fine.  What compiler is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've finally solved the problem as follows:

1) Make the BAT file set the default dir to 1 dir above the A and B dirs, ie, to the Apps dir, and invoke the make utility from there:

```
cd /f/Files/C/SW/Applications/Samples/C++Samples/Introductory/Classes/Apps/
make -f A/MakeC
```

2) Modify the makefile to access each header explicitly from the dir in which it is stored, create the obj and exe file in a specified dir and invoke the exe file in the specified dir:

```
CPP = g++
OFLAG = -o
CFLAG = -std=c++11 -c

# BAT file invoking MakeC sets default to ... Classes/Apps/
HADIR = ./A/
HBDIR = ./B/

# HADIR contains HA and HC
# HBDIR contains HB
HA = A
HC = C
HB = B

PROG1 = TestC

IHADIR = -I$(HADIR)
IHBDIR = -I$(HBDIR)

all : $(PROG1).o $(PROG1).exe run1

$(PROG1).o : $(HADIR)$(PROG1).cpp $(HADIR)$(HC).h $(HBDIR)$(HB).h $(HADIR)$(HA).h
#       Create obj file in HADIR explicitly
    $(CPP) $(OFLAG) $(HADIR)$@  $(CFLAG) $(IHADIR) $(IHBDIR) $<

$(PROG1).exe : $(HADIR)$(PROG1).o
#       Create exe file in HADIR explicitly
    $(CPP) $(OFLAG) $(HADIR)$@ $^

clean:
#       Specify dir explicitly
    rm $(HADIR)*.exe $(HADIR)*.o

run1:
#       Specify dir explicitly
    $(HADIR)$(PROG1)
```

As I've stated, I'm using g++ 4.8.1.

What worked for me, was to have the invoking BAT file set the default dir to one level above the dirs that contain the source files and in the makefile, specify the dirs explicitly.

---- EDIT ----
I'd like to suggest a possible reason for why this works.

First, notice that originally, the HADIR variable was set to ./ (the default dir).

As @lockcmpxchg8b said, the "default dir" could be interpreted as (a) wrt the original file or (b) the #included header file. These are the only 2 possibilities. Since the compiler can't find the #included header, it means it has selected the wrong possibility. This is obviously a version-specific gcc problem, since others can't repro the problem on later gcc versions.

Then, the solution is to avoid using ./ as a value for a dir symbol such as HADIR. Instead set the default dir outside make to another dir. In this case, it was done to the dir one level above A and B (viz. Apps). Then, the makefile's dir symbols can be made all wrt to that dir and would obviously not be ./

With values other than ./ (interpreted as the default dir by the compiler), the compiler interprets the value for the dir symbol as desired.

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) for information on which paths include searches.   Assuming you used the form `include "file"` (with quotes, not `#include <file>`, which is slightly different):

> By default, the preprocessor looks for header files included by the
>   quote form of the directive #include "file" first *relative to the
>   directory of the current file*, and then in a preconfigured list of
>   standard system directories. For example, if /usr/include/sys/stat.h
>   contains #include "types.h", GCC looks for types.h first in
>   /usr/include/sys, then in its usual search path.
>
> ...
>
> There are a number of command-line options you can use to add
>   additional directories to the search path. The most commonly-used
>   option is -Idir, which causes dir to be searched after the current
>   directory (for the quote form of the directive) and ahead of the
>   standard system directories. You can specify multiple -I options on
>   the command line, in which case the directories are searched in
>   left-to-right order.

notice that

> *directory of the current file*

refers to the directory that gcc was invoked from, as opposed to the directory of the source file (not the best wording).  So, if you invoke gcc from the directory of your .c file, you would want to add a `-IA -IB` flag to your compiler options, and then do not include paths in your `#include` directives (assuming gcc is being called from the directory of the .c file).

If you do want to include paths, they must be relative to the directory from which gcc was invoked, or one of the other include paths specified by a `-I` option.

---- EDIT -----

OK, I just read your updates, and it seems that TestC.c is in directory A, which I didn't get from your original post   This means you're compiling from directory A.   In this case I cannot reproduce your problem (at least not on my linux system):

```
[157]~/tmp/tmp9/A> find .. -type f -exec echo "------ " {} " ------" \; -exec more {} \;
------  ../A/A.h  ------
#pragma message "A.h"
// blank
------  ../A/C.h  ------
#pragma message "C.h"
#include "B.h"
------  ../A/testC.c  ------
#pragma "message file.c"
#include "C.h"

int main() {}
------  ../B/B.h  ------
#pragma message B.H
#include "A.h"
[157]~/tmp/tmp9/A> gcc -I. -I../B testC.c
In file included from testC.c:2:
C.h:1: note: #pragma message: C.h
In file included from C.h:2,
                 from testC.c:2:
../B/B.h:1: warning: expected a string after ‘#pragma message’
In file included from ../B/B.h:2,
                 from C.h:2,
                 from testC.c:2:
./A.h:1: note: #pragma message: A.h
[157]~/tmp/tmp9/A>
```

Your make command should echo the command used to build your test program -- attach that output to the question.

Comment: > In this case I cannot reproduce your problem (at least not on my linux system):  - This means the problem is platform-specific. I am working with GNU make on a WIndows 10 platform.

Comment: If you have the exact files I mentioned above, and run the exact same `gcc` command from the `A` directory, do you get a different result?   If you do, there's a bug in your version of gcc...

Answer (score 0):

Per https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.2/cpp_2.html#SEC6:

> **Section 2.1: Include Syntax**
>
> [#include with quotation marks] is used for header files of your own program. It searches for a file named file first **in the directory containing the current file**, then in the same directories used for <file>

Since we're discussing an include-with-quotes from another header, we must figure out what is considered the "current file".  Our options are:

1. the source file that included the original header
2. the original header itself (that now includes the subject header)

> **Section 2.2: Include Operation**
>
> The `#include' directive works by directing the C preprocessor **to scan the specified file as input before continuing with the rest of the current file**

To me, this wording implies that `#include` acts as an interruption to the processing of "current file", during which the included file becomes "current".  (Consider how this would have been written if the `#include` were interpreted as expanding *into* or *as a part of* the `#including` file.)  Also, if the quotation-mark version of `#include` were interpreted in the context of the #including file, it would break all the time and be mostly useless.

So the `#include "A.h"` within `B.h` looks for `A.h` relative to the location of `B.h`.  But `$HADIR` is not equal to `$HBDIR` so this lookup fails.

**Note however** that `-I` adds to the list of places that should be searched by `#include`-with-angle-brackets...which **should also** be searched after "directory of the current file" for `#include`-with-quotation-marks...so your compiler is doing something weird with it's search.

I also confirm that gcc 4.8.5 does not repro your issue.  Here's my test setup relative to the directory `Prog`

```
[Prog]$ find ..
../Prog
../Prog/A.h
../Prog/MakeC
../Prog/TestA.cpp
../Prog/TestC.cpp
../Prog/C.h
../B
../B/B.h
../B/TestB.cpp
```

Then building yields:

```
[Prog]$ make -f MakeC
g++ -std=c++11 -c -I./ -I../B/ TestC.cpp
g++ -o TestC.exe TestC.o
TestC
```

**What compiler are you using?**  (I'd bet a fair sum it's either old (circa gcc 2.9.6) or is customized by a vendor to target an embedded plaform)  I've seen interesting include path checks with some of these.

Here's a small contrived demo to show the proper behavior of `#include`-with-quotes:

inc/a.h

```
#pragma once
#include "b.h"
```

inc/b.h

```
#pragma once
extern int garbage;
```

test.c

```
#include "inc/a.h"
```

Then

```
$ gcc -E test.c
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "inc/a.h" 1

# 1 "inc/b.h" 1

extern int garbage;
# 4 "inc/a.h" 2
# 1 "test.c" 2
```

Note the main `.c` file includes `"inc/a.h"` directly, and there is no search path given on the compiler commandline, yet it still finds `"b.h"`.

Comment: > What compiler are you using?  I'm using g++ 4.8.1.

Answer (score -1):

I think in your "B.h", you should do: `#include "(Adir)/A.h"`

It seems like "A.h" is in a adjacent directory of the "B.h" directory. so when "B.h" tries to look for it in its current directory, it can't find it. 
I'm guessing `#include "../A/A.h"`

Comment: 1) The point of make files is that directory info should be placed there, rather than hard-coded in the source files.  2)  B.h shouldn't be searching for A.h in B dir; it should be searching in the A dir, which is the default dir set by the BAT file which invokes the makefile.

Comment: the weird thing to me, is that we usually add header from another directory, because we want to use them, not because they want to use us. make file can use "include directory" but still that wouldn't work for your purpose. because you're not including B, B is including you. so B should know where to look.

Comment: The situation is as follows: A.h is included by B.h which is included by C.h. It is a simple linear relationship: A.h <-- B.h <-- C.h. Here, the <-- arrow is read as "is referenced by". A.h and C.h are in a 1 dir (dir A) and B.h is in another dir (dir B).

Comment: No -- this is incorrect -- gcc will look for headers relative to the directory that the source is being compiled against -- not relative to the file currently being read.  (remember, `#include`ing a file is equivalent to replacing the `#include` directive with the included file, so the path the file came from is irrelevant).

Comment: @HardcoreHenry so in that case, `-I../B/` would work?

Comment: I had assumed that the main program was in the App directory, as opposed to in A.   If building from A, then you need a relative path, and `-I../B/` would allow visibility in the the `B` directory.  But in that case, `-I./` _should_ allow visibility into the `A` directory.   In any case, `B.h` does not try to look for an include file relative to its own directory.